# FLUTTER WINDOWS -- How to import 3rd party Library to flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ffi, flutter-windows

I want to make a windows application with flutter. But my app dependence with 3rd sdk

[image]

Please help me how to add *.lib to my project

Comment: You'll need to wrap it in an `ffi` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am new with flutter, can you give me more details about ffi

Comment: Yes, of course, there's a whole page devoted to it here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/c-interop

Comment: Thanks for your tips Richard Heap, but as my research, FFI just use for Android, IOS, i can not found the tutorial for windows. I think it can be done with CMakeLists.txt config in "windows/runner/" but i have not anything Knowledge about CMake :(

Comment: It can definitely be used on Windows. Check out the `win32` package as the mother of all Windows ffi packages.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for your help, i will try it now

Comment: @RichardHeap. Excuse me, i would like to know a problem that my sdk library only work on x86 machine, but flutter windows just run on x64. So how do i run flutter on x86 ?

Comment: That's a problem - no way around that. Get an updated copy of your library.